# How to fix regular polygons

Tags: java, graphics, polygon

I'm drawing polygons with multiple sides in java graphics. My algorithm works fine only when it comes to a small number of sides. How to fix it when the polygon has, for example, more than 50 sides?

```
    // PolygonsGUI. The value represents the number of sides of the polygon - Xiao 2019
    int x0 = dim.width / 2;
    int y0 = dim.height / 2;
    int r = Math.min(x0, y0) - 2 * gap;

    int[] xx = new int[value];
    int[] yy = new int[value];

    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        Double a = i * (Math.toRadians(360 / (double)value));
        xx[i] = (int) (x0 + (r * Math.sin(a)));
        yy[i] = (int) (y0 + (r * Math.cos(a)));
    }

    g.drawPolygon(xx, yy, value);
```

Comment: At what number of sides does it "stop working"? What does "stop working" mean?

Comment: not a JAVA coder but are you sure `sin,cos` need angle in degrees instead of radians?

Answer (score 0):

Your program is working just fine.  I drew lines from the center to each point on the polygon to show the radii.  Perhaps the problem is elsewhere in your code.

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PolygonDemo extends JPanel {
   JFrame frame  = new JFrame();
   int    width  = 500;
   int    height = 500;
   int    gap    = 20;
   int    value  = 50;
   int[]  xx     = new int[value];
   int[]  yy     = new int[value];
   int    x0     = width / 2;
   int    y0     = height / 2;

   public PolygonDemo() {
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(this);
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->  new PolygonDemo().start());
   }
   public void start() {

      int r = Math.min(x0, y0) - 2 * gap;

      for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
         Double a = i * (Math.toRadians(360 / (double) value));
         xx[i] = (int) (x0 + (r * Math.sin(a)));
         yy[i] = (int) (y0 + (r * Math.cos(a)));
      }

   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawPolygon(xx, yy, value);
      for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
         g.drawLine(x0, y0, xx[i], yy[i]);
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it. it's because of types.